# Laravel 5.5 groupBy with sum and first option

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table with some same id so I display them groupBy option with sum. I have many column like id, item_name, rate, quantity, value Here is my code.

```
$orders = Order::where('item_id', $id)
    ->where('delivery_status', 1)
    ->groupBy('item_id')
    ->selectRaw('sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(value) as value, item_id')
    ->pluck('item_id','quantity', 'value');
```

By this I got three column with id and quantity and value with sum. My problem is that I also want to display other column like item_name, rate, delivery_status etc. and  I don't want to sum them like rate. How can I display them? I can groupBy also with item_name and it works but can not group with rate because other items may also have same rate.

Comment: As far as I know pluck only supports two parameters, first will be the values, and the second keys from the returned array, so you can use get() instead.

Comment: Ok. I think I should try with get(), but how I get multiple column? what I have to include in selectRow() for other column like rate or item_name? I have tried with many options like first(), get(), and also sum()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `pluck`, as that will only return the columns you have specified. Instead, try using `get` to return all the table columns:

```
$orders = Order::where([
    'item_id' => $id,
    'delivery_status' => 1
])
    ->groupBy('item_id')
    ->selectRaw('orders.*, sum(quantity) as quantity, sum(value) as value, item_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't return other columns like rate, item_name that I also want to display

Comment: I forgot a part of the select, I've updated the answer.

Comment: That is what I wanted! Thanks